# Framework, css or theme to develop html that works for Windows Mobile 6.1 Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-mobile-6.1

I need to develop a simple web interface for a Motorola Scanner running Windows Mobile 6.1 to scan in products into an inventory system I am developing using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.

Is there any framework, theme, css, or anything out there to write html that works for Windows Mobile 6.1 Internet Explorer?. Nothing standard appears to work, most css properties don't show up properly and doing the simplest thing is just a nightmare because I don't even know why is not working.